# How to retrieve data from firebase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code for getting data from firebase database :

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Root").child("User1").child("chat1")
 .observeSingleEvent(of: .value , with: { snapshot in

    if snapshot.exists() {

        let recent = snapshot.value as!  NSDictionary

         print(recent)
})
```

There is a problem with the result of snapshot, the `print(recent)` sometimes prints all values of that child (10 values) which is the thing I want, but some time it prints only two values of that child I don't know why.

How to fix this ?

This is my database structure :

[image]

Comment: Your code looks solid! Your bug might be elsewhere my friend...

Comment: Having said that, try printing `recent.count` to be extra sure your analysis is correct.

Comment: @pauloMattos this time only got one value and the print of count is `1` :(

Comment: Your third node is "chat1" or "Chat1"?

Comment: @pauloMattos actually I printed the `snapshot.ref` then copy it and paste it in the browser , it's the correct reference and it has all the 10 values !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can not comment and I just want to ask something, I will remove this answer later on, but is your data in sync? Did you call the method yourreference.keepSynced(true)?

Comment: No , why ? can you explain

Comment: Scroll to " keeping data fresh" https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

Comment: you may want to change your answer or make it clear , thanks

Comment: Nice! Please don't delete your answer because your solution appears solid!